# Why costum actions are not working - Rasa Core

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

**Rasa Core version**: `0.13.0`
**Rasa Core SDK version**: `0.12.1`

**Python version**: `3.6`

**Operating system** (windows, osx, ...): `Windows 10`

**Issue**:
`rasa_core.processor  - Encountered an exception while running action 'email_verification'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Make sure to fix the exception in your custom code.`

**More Info**:
I run `python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions` and `python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/nlu --endpoints endpoints.yml` < but when I run this part(second) and then I run train_online.py I get:
`OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted: ('0.0.0.0', 5005)` cant run both at the same time, the reason that I wanted to run both at the same time is that I read on a github issue that I might solve the main Issue with custom actions.

Action file:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import requests
from rasa_core_sdk import Action
from rasa_core_sdk.events import SlotSet


class EmailVerification(Action):

    def name(self):
        return "email_verification"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        # type: # (Dispatcher, DialogueStateTracker, Domain) -> List[Event]

        user_email_address = tracker.get_slot('email')
        base_url = "http://apilayer.net/api/check?access_key=8c47e63ccc2e06553e4daba9eadd23d3&email={email}"
        url = base_url.format(**{'email': user_email_address})
        res = requests.get(url)
        emailVer = res.json()['format_valid']
        if emailVer == True:
            response = "Your email is valid, thank you."
        else:
            response = "Your email is Invalid, please retype."

        dispatcher.utter_message(response)
        return [SlotSet("email", user_email_address)]
```

**Content of endpoint file** (if used & relevant):

```
action_endpoint:
  url: http://localhost:5055/webhook

#nlg:
#url: http://localhost:5056/nlg

nlu:
    url: http://localhost:5000

core_endpoint:
  url: http://localhost:5056
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like another process is occupying port 5005. Either you stop the other process running on port 5005 or you start the action server on a different port, e.g:

```
python -m rasa_core_sdk.endpoint --actions actions --port 9000
```

and in your endpoint file (seems this is currently wrong (`5055` instead of `5005`), make sure it is the same as used by the action endpoint):

```
action_endpoint:
  url: http://localhost:9000/webhook
#other endpoints
```